# Can a public domain character be subject to trademarks?

Tags: copyright, trademark

Can a fictional character that is out of copyright protection still have trademark protection? What uses of such a character are permitted or not permitted? Please provide a current real-world example.

Comment: Sure, why not?  If you look in your local trademark registry, I'm sure you'll see some examples.

Comment: The short answer is "yes" but an answer with support and examples will take longer to write.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - I’m posting a screenshot of the USPTO TESS database after a search for “little tramp”, Charlie Chaplin’s character.

The two issued trademarks are now dead but they were issued.

[image]

Details of first trademark -

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### [Yes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PublicDomainCharacter)

Some notable examples of characters not subject to copyright in at least some jurisdictions but active trademarks are:

[image: Bugs Bunny]

[image: James Bond]

[image: Thor]

[image: Alice in Wonderland]

Note that the works these particular representations of those characters are taken from may still be subject to copyright: Thor the character has no copyright; Thor that looks like Chris Hemsworth with the gear Chris war in the Marvel movies is subject to copyright.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148180/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-can-a-public-domain-character-be-subject-to-trade); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.